# HTML table remove border

Tags: html, asp.net

I have issue to remove the border of table inside the gridview. The table is inside the itemtemplate. How to do that? Please help. Thanks

Below is my code.

```
                             <StdUI:GridView ID="gvSI" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HideHeader="true"
                        HideFooter="true" Visible="False">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <table class="style1" border="1" style="border-width: 1px; border-color: #C0C0C0;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td rowspan="3" style="text-align: center">
                                                End of Certificate Year
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="style2" colspan="5">
                                                <btd>
                                                Guaranteed
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">
                                                Total Benefits&nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style2" rowspan="2">
                                                Yearly Contribution
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="style2" rowspan="2">
                                                Wakalah Fee
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">
                                                PRF
                                            </td>
                                            <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                                                Death Benefit (Nonaccidental cause)
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="style2" rowspan="2">
                                                Death Benefit (Accidental cause)
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="style4" rowspan="2">
                                                Surrender Value
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style5">
                                                Death Benefit (Non- accidental cause)
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="style2">
                                                Death Benefit (Accidental cause)
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="style2">
                                                Surrender Value
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
 <table class="style1" border="0">
 <tr>
<td style="text-align: center" >
 <asp:label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Col1") %>' >
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center">
 <asp:label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Col2") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center">
 <asp:label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col3") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="76">
 <asp:label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col4") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="65">
 <asp:label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col5") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="76">
 <asp:label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col6") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="80">
 <asp:label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col7") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="77">
 <asp:label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col8") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="76">
 <asp:label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col9") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                           </Columns>
                               </StdUI:GridView>
```

Current design
http://postimg.org/image/ws3s2agbl/

Comment: can you please also show the css used in class="table1"

Answer (score 0):

Use `<table class="table1" border="0">` instead of `<tr style="border:0">`.

**Update**

try gridview property `GridLines="None"`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table class="style1" border="0" style="border:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hide it by following CSS
add it inside the css

```
td{
 border: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use GridLines="None" which is a property of gridview. 
In the table use border="0" like this -

```
<table class="style1" border="0" style="border-width: 1px; border-color: #C0C0C0;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two methods to avoid border of table.
One is declaring table border to 0 i.e `<table border=0>` or not decaring the table border.
The other is using the CSS. i.e

```
table
{
border : 0px;
}
```

(or)

```
table
{
border : none;
}
```